# How to replace records with maps in MatchHead of Match Specification?

Tags: select, erlang, maps, matching, ets

An Erlang match specification supports the following pattern with record in MatchHead of Match Specification:

```
#recordName{field1=1, field='$1', _='_'}
```

This matches all the `recordName` records from a table which has `field1 == 1` and also does an implicit binding of `field` to be used later in MatchBody.

Is there anything similar with maps?

I tried (apart from Google) the following syntax(es):

```
% ERROR: * 1: only association operators '=>' are allowed in map construction
#{key:=1, key:='$1', _:='_'}
```

and

```
% ERROR: * 1: illegal use of variable '_' in map
#{key=>1, key=>$1', _=>'_'}
```

Is it possible to do it and the syntax is documented somewhere I could not find? Or, is it a wrong way of thinking about maps replacing records?

TIA

EDIT:
Perhaps it isn't supported yet. Just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988993/erlang-17-recommend-to-use-map-replace-record-but-how-to-make-mnesia-support-map/25226601#25226601) post.

Answer (score 1):

```
1> M = #{k1 => 1, k2 => 2, k3 => 3}.
#{k1 => 1,k2 => 2,k3 => 3}
2> #{k1:=1,k2:=V} = M.
#{k1 => 1,k2 => 2,k3 => 3}
3> V.
2
4> %% but you cannot do
4> ets:fun2ms(fun(#{key1:=V, key2:=R}) when V == 1 -> R end).
Error: ets:fun2ms requires fun with single variable or tuple parameter
{error,transform_error}
5> 
5> %% while it is possible to do
5> ets:fun2ms(fun({V,R}) when V == 1 -> R end).
[{{'$1','$2'},[{'==','$1',1}],['$2']}]
6> %% or
6> rd(foo,{k1,k2}).
foo
7> ets:fun2ms(fun(#foo{k1=V,k2=R}) when V == 1 -> R end).
[{#foo{k1 = '$1',k2 = '$2'},[{'==','$1',1}],['$2']}]
8> %% or even
8> ets:fun2ms(fun(#foo{k1=1,k2=R}) -> R end).            
[{#foo{k1 = 1,k2 = '$1'},[],['$1']}]
9>
```